# Density of the canonical embedding $J: E \mapsto E^{**}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, duality-theorems

> Assume that E is $ \mathbb K$−Banach space and denote by $J : E → E^{∗∗}$ the canonical embedding of $E$ into its bidual $E^{∗∗}$.

By Goldstine Theorem, I know that in this case $J(E)$ is dense in $E^{∗∗}$ with respect to the weak* topology $σ(E^{∗∗},E^∗)$.

But why is $J(E)$ not dense with respect to the norm topology or the weak topology $σ(E^{∗∗},E^{∗∗∗})$? Could someone give me an example of those cases or explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical embedding $J \colon E \to E^{\ast\ast}$ is isometric, i.e. $\lVert J(x)\rVert_{E^{\ast\ast}} = \lVert x\rVert_E$ for all $x\in E$. Since $E$ is a Banach space, it follows that $J(E)$ is a complete subspace of $E^{\ast\ast}$, and therefore closed.

As a linear subspace, $J(E)$ is convex, and a convex subset of a Hausdorff locally convex space is weakly closed if and only if it is closed in the original topology. Thus it follows that $J(E)$ is also $\sigma(E^{\ast\ast}, E^{\ast\ast\ast})$-closed.

Hence $J(E)$ is norm-dense or weakly dense in $E^{\ast\ast}$ only if $E$ is reflexive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But why "a convex subset of a **Hausdorff** locally convex space"? Where does the Hausdorff space (the separity property) come from?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter, I'm just used to saying "Hausdorff locally convex" since many things need Hausdorffness, and sometimes do so without it being necessary. But since we're dealing with a dual space, Hausdorffness is given.

Comment: So, in my space it would mean that $J(E)$, a convex subset of a Banach space, is weakly closed if and only if it is closed in the original topology. Even if it is not a Hausdorff space, this is true in this case?

Comment: Well, here we have the Banach space $E^{\ast\ast}$, which is Hausdorff, so the question doesn't arise. But if $F$ is a locally convex space with topology $\tau$, and $C\subset F$ is convex, then the $\tau$-closure of $C$ is the same as the $\sigma(F,F^{\ast})$-closure, whether $\tau$ is a Hausdorff topology or not.

Comment: Great :) Thank you for taking time to answer my questions!

Answer (score 1):

Let $E= c_0(\mathbb{N})$, the set of sequences $(a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_n \mapsto 0$ when $n \mapsto \infty$. Define $\|(a_n)\|= \max_{n\in \mathbb{N}} |a_n|$.

Then  $E^*=\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$, and $E^{**}= \ell_{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$.

But $E$ is not dense in $E^{**}$ for the norm $\|. \|_{\infty}$

Comment: you mean by $l_0$ the sequence space $c_0$, right? I think I had a different notation for it.

Comment: @TigerLa: yes, $\ell_0(\mathbb{N})$ is $c_0$.

Comment: Ah, now I understand it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @marco2013 $\ell_0$ is rather unusual notation to me in this context. It is used to mean [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#When_p_.3D_0).

Comment: @A.G.  Thanks, I have corrected.